# What are the error codes and messages returned for `apt-get update` failures?

Tags: apt, updates

Where can I find the error codes returned by a failed `apt-get update` command? 
Can you please point me to the code, or specs, that calls out the error messages returned from an `apt-get update failure`? Thanks.

Go ahead and ignore the rest of this question if you can answer the first one. Bonus points if you can add additional information.

What are the recommended solutions to resolve those problems?

Currently, I have three error codes that I have commonly encountered and I am wondering if there are more that I should be aware of.

1. NO_PUBKEY
2. BADSIG
3. 403 Forbidden
4. 404 Not Found
5. Duplicate sources.list entry

Here are the workarounds for the errors that I am aware of:

#### NO_PUBKEY

Solution: add new public gpg key to my trusted chain by running the command:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <insert pub_key_here>`

#### BADSIG

Solution: re-add key

`sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com <insert key here>`

#### 403 Forbidden

Solution: ?

#### 404 Not found

Solution: Site is unavailable. Either wait until site returns, or remove repository from sources.list.

#### Duplicate sources.list entry

Solution: ?

How many other error codes are there returned by `apt-get update` that prevent users from updating their software? Is there documentation somewhere to identify similar issues?

I understand the risks involved when I am implicitly trusting third parties when I am adding their keys to my trusted chain. I am looking to identify the known errors generated by a failed `apt-get update` and the solutions to allow me to continue to update my packages.

Comment: For the 404 error, check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa to add more info.

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for a community wiki.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm saji89, not sajai89. :)

Comment: Thankyou for the correction. :) Kudos for your effort. It is good to have a community wiki for this.

Comment: I think the downvotes are due to the fact that this question isn't going to help anybody. It's better to have a question for every specific case, otherwise giving solutions is impossible. For example: the two HTTP errors (403 and 404) can't be "fixed". It's the HTTP server that gives such errors, not APT. And the HTTP server is out of your control, so you can't do anything about it, except contacting the administrator.

Comment: The other errors are already discussed in many other questions, and even if they weren't, they should go in separate, ad-hoc questions, so that they can be easily found using a simple search.

Comment: @maggotbrain: I agree with you and appreciate your efforts. However having a unique big question is not going to be helpful. Try for example searching for "apt no_pubkey" and look at the results. What are the chances of having this question on the top of the results? What are the changes of having an ad-hoc question entitled "How do I resolve the NO_PUBKEY error?" (or a better title) on the top?